# Poner elemento que tiene el foco a la vista

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo un problema, tengo una lista en la que cuando hago click en alguno de los elementos le da el foco pero como que cambia de posicion la vista, y se pierde el elemento donde he hecho click, que puede causar esto?

Un saludo

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, podrías dar mas detalles y sobretodo poner el código de html para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Tengo una lista de elementos que son input, pero esta metida en un recuadro, cosa que cuando hago scroll se van ocultando. Cuando hago click en uno de ellos sale el teclado, y en el elemento donde he hecho el foco, se pierde.

Comment: Hola Ruben, puedes mostrar el código donde haces la selección del elemento para así poder ayudarte ya que con la simple información que nos dices no podemos hacer mucho